# Let $X,Y$ be two random discrete uniform independent variables such that $X,Y \sim Unif([N])$, prove that $(X+Y) mod \ N \ \sim Unif({0,1,..,N-1})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

What I have tried so far:

$$\text{let } Z = X+Y  \\
P(Z=i) = P(X+Y=i) = P(X=Y-i,Y=y) \\
\text{X and Y are independent}  \\
P(Z=i)=P(X=Y-i)P(Y=y) \\
P(Z=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}P(X=Y-i)P(Y=y)
$$
Now since the question is asking for $(X+Y) modN$:

$$P(Z \ mod \ N = i)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}P(X=Y-i)P(Y=y)$$
I got stuck here and didn't understand how to use the $mod \ N$ in the summation, any hints or help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: $Z \equiv i \bmod N$ with $0\le i \lt N$ if and only if $X+Y=i$ or $X+Y=i+N$

Comment: Yes, as @Henry says; so there are $(i-1)$ ways for $X+Y=i$, and $N-(i-1)$ ways for $X+Y= i+N$. This makes a probability of $N/N^2= 1/N$, for each $i$.